# highcharts arearange to turn off x-axix line

Tags: highcharts

IM working with arearange type of chart using highchart, and Im looking for a way to turn off the x-axis dispolay completely only left the y-axis. I tried setting `lineWidth` to 0 but it didn't do it.

I am also trying to have the y-axis to display values every other step. is there a way to do so?

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eatdoku/u5xmk4nk/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting tickWidth to 0 and removing labels to effectively hide the axis.

```
xAxis: {
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: { enabled: false } 
},
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mvhw7x8/)

For the yAxis issue, using tickInterval might help you. If you can post a JSFiddle of your chart it would help us to see your issue.